# Custom Cursor not appearing in all pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a portfolio website and am looking to implement a custom cursor. Currently the cursor is working on the Profile page but when I navigate to a project page, the cursor reverts to default. I have tried looking at previous posts and other articles which suggested I use the useContext hook to share the cursor but i have been unable to implement this correctly so far. Everytime i navigate to a Project page, the cursor is the default cursor (I have checked disabling it in css too).  Would someone be able to help suggest a solution for this issue please? The cursor colour and size changes on any element that has the textEnter/textLeave attributes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

**Index.js**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([


 {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "projects/:projectId",
    element: <Project />,
    loader: ({ params }) => {
      return ProjectData.find((project) => project.id == params.projectId);
    },
  },

]);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {


 return (
    <div>
      <CursorContextProvider>
        <ScrollToTop>
          <Cursor />
          <main className="App bg-blue-950 min-h-screen" />
        </ScrollToTop>
      </CursorContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Profile.js**

```
const Profile = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScroll();
  const introOpacity = useTransform(
    scrollY,
    [0, 5, 25, 50, 75, 80],
    [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0]
  );
  const bioOpacity = useTransform(
    scrollY,
    [90, 150, 210, 280, 320, 360],
    [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
  );

  // const cursor = useContext(CursorContext);

  // console.log(cursor);

  const location = useLocation();

  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });

  const [cursorVariant, setCursorVariant] = useState("default");

  const mouseMove = (e) => {
    setMousePosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
    };
  }, [location]);

  const textEnter = () => {
    setCursorVariant("text");
  };

  const textLeave = () => {
    setCursorVariant("default");
  };

  const linkEnter = () => {
    setCursorVariant("link");
  };

  const variants = {
    default: {
      x: mousePosition.x - 16,
      y: mousePosition.y - 16,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(206, 67, 159)",
    },
    text: {
      height: 120,
      width: 120,
      x: mousePosition.x - 60,
      y: mousePosition.y - 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(206, 67, 159)",
      mixBlendMode: "lighten",
    },
    link: {
      height: 60,
      width: 60,
      x: mousePosition.x - 30,
      y: mousePosition.y - 30,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(206, 67, 159)",
      mixBlendMode: "lighten",
    },
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 profile">
        <aside class="h-full">
          <div
            className="ml-12 m-5 profile-image-container bg-"
            onMouseEnter={textEnter}
            onMouseLeave={textLeave}
          >
            <img
              src={profile}
              alt="profile"
              className="rounded-full mt-4"
            ></img>
            <p className="text-left mt-8 bio-text">
              Former Product Owner who has made the switch to Full Stack
              development
              <img src={technologist} className="emoji"></img>
            </p>
            <div className="flex flex-col details-container mt-1">
              <h4 className="underline">My details:</h4>
              <div className="mt-4 flex flex-row justify-start items-center">
                <img src={linkedin} className="language"></img>
                <p
                  className="grow text-start ms-8"
                  onMouseEnter={linkEnter}
                  onMouseLeave={textLeave}
                >
                    See my Linkedin here
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4 flex flex-row justify-start items-center">
                <img src={cv} className="language"></img>
                <p
                  className="grow text-start ms-8"
                  onMouseEnter={linkEnter}
                  onMouseLeave={textLeave}
                >
                  <a href="#">See my CV here </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4 flex flex-row justify-start items-center">
                <img src={github} className="language"></img>
                <p
                  className="grow text-start ms-8"
                  onMouseEnter={linkEnter}
                  onMouseLeave={textLeave}
                >
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4 flex flex-row justify-start items-center">
                <img src={gmail} className="language"></img>
                <p
                  className="grow text-start ms-8"
                  onMouseEnter={linkEnter}
                  onMouseLeave={textLeave}
                >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-5 languages-container">
              <h4 className="underline">Languages:</h4>
              <div className="flex flex-col">
            </div>
          </div>
        </aside>
        <section class="col-start-2 col-end-10">
          <motion.div
            className="cursor"
            variants={variants}
            animate={cursorVariant}
          ></motion.div>
          <div
            className="col-span-3 ms-20"
            onMouseEnter={textEnter}
            onMouseLeave={textLeave}
          >
            <motion.div
              style={{ opacity: introOpacity }}
              className="w-full h-96"
            >
              <h1 className="text-left mt-24 w-full">
               Nice to meet you!
              </h1>
              <p className="text-left mt-8">
                Scroll to learn a little more....
              </p>
            </motion.div>
            <div className="scroll-container">
              <div className="icon-scroll"></div>
            </div>
            <section>
              <motion.div style={{ opacity: bioOpacity }} className="w-8/12">
                <p className="text-left">
                  <h3
                    className="underline"
                    onMouseEnter={textEnter}
                    onMouseLeave={textLeave}
                  >
                    About me
                  </h3>
                    <LanguagesList />
              </motion.div>
              <motion.div>
                <p className="text-left">
                  <h3 className="underline">Projects</h3>
                  <Projects onMouseEnter={linkEnter} onMouseLeave={textLeave} />
                </p>
              </motion.div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

**Project.js**

```
const Project = (props) => {
// const [setCursorVariant] = useContext(CursorContext)
const project = useLoaderData();

return (
    <div className="bg-blue-950 min-h-full m-2 projectPage">
        <Header/>
        <ScrollToTop/>
            <div className="projectInfoCard">
                <Link to={"/"}>Go back to home</Link>
                <Link to={"/"}>See source code</Link>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-center">
                    <h1>{`${project.Name}`}</h1>
                    <CarouselContainer project={project}/>
                    <p>{`${project.Description}`}</p>
                    <TechnologyList languages={project.TechStack}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
    </div>
)

}

export default Project;
```

**Cursor.js**

```
export const CursorContext = createContext();

const Cursor = () => {
        const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
        });

        // const location = useLocation();
      
        const [cursorVariant, setCursorVariant] = useState("default");
      
        const mouseMove = (e) => {
          setMousePosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
        };
      
        useEffect(() => {
          window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
          };
        }, []);
      
       const textEnter = () => {
          setCursorVariant("text");
        };
      
        const textLeave = () => {
          setCursorVariant("default");
        };
      
        const linkEnter = () => {
          setCursorVariant("link");
        };

        
        const variants = {
            default: {
            x: mousePosition.x - 16,
            y: mousePosition.y - 16,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(206, 67, 159)",
            },
            text: {
            height: 120,
            width: 120,
            x: mousePosition.x - 60,
            y: mousePosition.y - 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(206, 67, 159)",
            mixBlendMode: "lighten",
            },
            link: {
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            x: mousePosition.x - 30,
            y: mousePosition.y - 30,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(206, 67, 159)",
            mixBlendMode: "lighten",
            },
        };

}

export default Cursor;
```

**Home.js**

```
  const Home = (props) => {
  const [textEnter, textLeave, linkEnter, cursorVariant, variants] =
    useContext(CursorContext);
  return (
    <Profile
      textEnter={textEnter}
      textLeave={textLeave}
      linkEnter={linkEnter}
      cursorVariant={cursorVariant}
      variants={variants}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is `App` used?

Comment: Not directly related to the problem: But please be very careful when customising the cursors appearance/functionality, it's very easy to produce something you like but visitors to your site will hate. E.g. It looks like you are effectively "smoothing" mouse movement using a `motion.div`, which I personally would use as a cue to immediately leave your site.

Comment: Hi Konrad, thanks for coming back to me. Looking at the code again, App wasn't being used but when i change the "Home" component in index js to the "App" component, i still face the same issue.

Comment: ```<React.StrictMode>
    <CursorContextProvider>
          <Cursor />
    <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
</CursorContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>```

Comment: Thanks for the tip DBS, i will take a look again. Unfortunately I tried your latest comment Konrad but i haven't got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see of your code you are not rendering the `App` component in the ReactTree with the routes and routed content. If you then try to render `App` on only one of the routes, then navigating away from that route will also remove the cursor context from the ReactTree.

`App` should be rendered in the ReactTree such that it is always available to the components below it, e.g. the router, routes, and routed content.

Rename `App` to something more informative, like `AppLayout`, and have it consume and render a `children` prop. I suspect you want the routes/content to be rendered into the `main` element, but `children` just needs to be rendered somewhere in `AppLayout`.

AppLayout

```
function AppLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <CursorContextProvider>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <Cursor />
        <main className="App bg-blue-950 min-h-screen">
          {children}
        </main>
      </CursorContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.html

Wrap the `RouterProvider` in the `AppLayout` so the cursor context is available to all routes, e.g. the entire application.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
 {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "projects/:projectId",
    element: <Project />,
    loader: ({ params }) => {
      return ProjectData.find((project) => project.id == params.projectId);
    },
  },
]);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppLayout>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AppLayout>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Apologies i have added the Cursor component code for context. It's not working just yet but i think this is because i am unclear on how CursorContextProvider should be used. I am passing it a value of CursorContext from the Cursor Component

Comment: @d709859 The provider component only needs to wrap the sub-ReactTree it is providing a value to. Where is a `CursorContext.Provider` component used to provide a value? Perhaps you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect?

Comment: Hi @Drew Reese, i am having issues getting the running codesandbox up and running. As soon as i do, i will post the url here, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Drew, [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/dgraham09/portfolio-site/master) is the link for the sandbox if you have time to take a look. The browser is a pink circle when it runs correctly.

Comment: @d709859 Thanks, I'm able to open & run that sandbox, but there is no cursor displayed. The `Cursor` component doesn't return anything though. Is the `Cursor` component supposed to render the "pink circle" you reference? The `CursorContextProvider` component renders a `CursorContext.Provider` but provides the literal `CursorContext` context object as the context value. What exactly are you trying to provide & consume as a context value? If you are just rendering a custom cursor I don't exactly see how a React context helps here.

Comment: Hi @Drew, The cursor is now showing in the `Profile` component as i added the code that was in the `Cursor` Component into it. Thanks, I was trying to use the `CursorContext` component to share the cursor across components. Is there a way to move the cursor code out of the `Profile` compnent and have the `Cursor` component render in App.js? I'm not sure what to return in the `Cursor` component so that all pages have access to it, thank you in advance!

Comment: @d709859 Sorry, I still am not seeing any custom cursor being rendered in your app. What is the code that creates/renders the custom cursor? Whatever it is it should probably be moved to a central location, e.g. a component that exists for the life of the app, e.g. like the `App` component.

Comment: sorry it's the first time i have used code sandbox. Could you try again? I have moved the code that creates the cursor and renders it into the `Cursor` component. The cursor component now shows on both pages, i just need to work out how to  get the textEnter/textLeave etc to work across the components (so the cursor animation happens when a user hovers over text) - should i move some of the cursor functions into the `App` component and pass it as props to `cursor` component? Thanks for taking the time to help me out with this

Comment: @d709859 Ok, looks like the `Cursor` component you are rendering in `AppLayout` in `App.js` renders the custom cursor UI, it works on both routes the app renders. The `CursorContextProvider` isn't needed since it doesn't provide anything useful, so removing it should be completely fine. That said, that motion springing/snapping on the mouse is actually quite disorientating. I agree with DBS's sentiment regarding the mouse movement as I also find it quite a turnoff.

Comment: Thanks @Drew, i've removed the provider and everything is working fine. I have also removed the cursor effects when it hovers over the text as recommended. Thanks a lot for patiently helping me out with this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @d709859 Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!